# Expectation for arriving earlier and later

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I was thinking to get these using the first and second moment by $E(X)=\frac{(b+a)}{2} $ and $E(X^2)=\frac{b^3-a^3}{3b-3a}$ for $a=2,b=8$, but I don't think this is the solution. I have found some sort of solution with order statistics and Beta distributions, but I would like to solve it without it, in a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy can you solve it by calculating the expectation of  min and Max

(b)

The distribution of $Z=max(X,Y)$ is

$$F_Z(z)=\Big(\frac{z-2}{6}\Big)^2$$

Derivating you get $Z$ density with expectation

$$E(Z)=\int_2^8 z\frac{z-2}{18}dz=6 pm$$

Similar result for (a): find the distribution of $U=min(X,Y)$ then the expectation

Result: 4 pm

---

The CDF of an uniform is

$$F_X(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}=\frac{x-2}{8-2}$$

The CDF of the Max is

$$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(X\leq z; Y\leq z)=P(X\leq z)P(Y\leq z)=\Big(\frac{z-2}{8-2}\Big)^2$$

---

The CDF of min is

$$P(U>u)=P(X>u,Y>u)=P(X>u)P(Y>u)=\Big(1-\frac{u-2}{6}\Big)^2$$

Thus

$$F_U(u)=P(U\leq u)=1-\Big(\frac{8-u}{6}\Big)^2$$

Derivating you get the density with expectation

$$E(U)=\int_2^8 u\Big(\frac{8-u}{18}\Big)du=4$$

Comment: How did you get $F_Z$? Isn't it constant 1/6?

Comment: @andrei1234589 the density is constant but not the CDF. Please accept the answer if you want more details

Comment: And why is it squared? I mean $f_Z=(x-2)/6$...

Comment: I know the density function. But I do not understand how can you get the min and max functions, since these two functions are equal

Comment: @andrei1234589 : I added full details for (b). Do a similar reasoning for (a). It is not difficult

Comment: @andrei1234589 this approach is consistent with the approach used for extreme values it seems. Stuart Coles has a good book on this topic, *Introduction to the Modeling of Extreme Values*. That is the basis for picking the max and min distributions. tommik, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks @tommik now it really makes sense

Comment: @andrei1234589 to find the CDF of min it is easier to start calculating $P(U>u)$. This CDF will result in $F_{min}=1-(1-F)^2$

Comment: I mean the minimum would be $P(X\ge z;Y \ge z)=P(X \ge z)P( Y \ge z)$

Comment: @bnmyui exactly. Go on and find the result

Comment: I got $1-2(\frac{x-2}{6})^2 + (\frac{x-2}{6})^4$ and I don't think it looks like yours

Comment: @bnmyui see my edits with all the details...

Comment: Thanks! It's not that clar why we need ">" but I'll try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** (almost solution):

Put $\xi$ = arrival time of customer A, $\eta$ = arrival time of customer B. Then the time of first (earlier) arrival is $\zeta = \min(\xi, \eta)$. Thus we know $P(\zeta > x) = P( \xi > x, \eta >x) = P( \xi > x)P(\eta >x)$. For nonnegative r.v. $\zeta$ we have:
$$E \zeta = \int_{0}^{\infty} P( \zeta>x) dx.$$
Hence we know $E \zeta $.

Put $\bar{\zeta}$ = time of second arrival $= \max(\xi, \eta)$, then $\bar{\zeta} + \zeta =   \min(\xi, \eta) + \max(\xi, \eta) = \xi + \eta$. As $E\xi= E\eta = \frac{b+a}{2}$ we get that
$$E\bar{\zeta} + E\zeta = E(\xi + \eta) = b+a$$ and thus we know $E\bar{\zeta} $.